# Identify cell containing given text in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: search, libreoffice-calc

Is there a function in LO Calc that will find a **cell** with the given text?

The search and find functions appear to give a location within a string. That is, if I search for the text "a" within two cells, one of which contains "xxxa" and the other contains "bbb", the answer will be 4.

This is not what I need. I need to find which cell has the text in question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use the **[`MATCH()`](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#MATCH)** function. Since it supports [regular expressions](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Regular_Expressions_in_Calc), you can use MATCH() to search for partial strings.

Here's an example:

[image]

The lookup array is `A1:A4`, the search criterion is `.*a.*` (this is a regular expression, for syntax see link above). The result of the formula `=MATCH(".*a.*";A1:A4;0)` is `2`, since the **second** cell in the lookup array is the first cell that matches the search pattern.

## EDIT:

Regarding the regular expression: [here's a list of regular expression characters](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/List_of_Regular_Expressions). The expression `.*a.*` consists of:

- the literal `a`, matching a single `a` character;
- the dot `.`, matching any character;
- the asterisk `*`, a quantifier, meaning "zero or more", regarding the preceding character.

So, the regex pattern matches every cell content containing an `a`, preceded and followed by any number of other characters. To get acquainted with regular expressions, check the [RegExr](http://regexr.com/) or the [online regex tester](https://regex101.com/).

Comment: I've added some info on regular expressions - hope it's more clear now.

Comment: Note: You must use DOUBLE "" quotes to get this to work.

Answer (score 3):

*Note to readers: LibreOffice added wildcards and regular expressions, generally compatible with other spreadsheet applications like Excel, around version 5.  At the time of this question, I was using the latest version of LO in the Debian repository, which pre-dated that.  If you are reading this now, the accepted answer is the best solution.  I can think of only one case where you might want to use this answer as an alternative: if you're stuck with an ancient version of LO Calc (which sometimes happens with some featherweight distros that use custom packages).  I'll leave this answer in place just in case.*

---

Here's a workaround that uses a helper column (it can be used without a helper column if your version of LO Calc supports SUMPRODUCT, which I'll show at the end).

[image: example]

You can hide column B.  Cell B1 contains:

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("a",A1))*ROW()
```

Copy that down the column as needed.  This provides the row number if the cell contains "a", otherwise zero.  The cell address that you want is in D1:

```
=ADDRESS(SUM(B1:B3),1)
```

The sum of the matching row and a bunch of zeros gives you the row, and the column is known.  You could use these values directly inside a formula rather than creating a text representation of the address.

You can eliminate the helper column with SUMPRODUCT, in which case the formula in D1 would be:

```
=ADDRESS(SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("a",A1:A3))*ROW(A1:A3)),1)
```

SUMPRODUCT treats the range as an array and does what the helper column does in one step.